# Ionic replacing localStorage with persistent storage synchronously

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-local-storage

I've ran into the issue with my Ionic app where localStorage is getting wiped due to lower memory. I've investigated many different persistence mechanisms sqlite, Cordova native storage, etc.

My issue.... localStorage was implemented as synchronous calls, as a result my entire codebase is consuming localStorage calls that way. Almost every persistence option I've looked at is asynchronous (which while a good thing), would be a huge undertaking to refactor code base to consume. Am I pretty much stuck refactoring ?

I'm looking for any suggestions or guidance on how to tackle this dilemma.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue on inheriting a legacy codebase and ultimately there was no synchronous solution: the entire codebase had to be reworked, with almost 2000 individual synchronous references to local storage. Even if you wrote your own Cordova plugin, the Cordova plugin API is itself inherently async. You might also have to bite the bullet and rework the codebase for async interaction.

Comment: Thank you @DaveAlden, I was hoping to get a different answer... ;) But I've now begun on my own refactor of the code base per your comment.